# MysqlCommand switching connection unexpectedtly

Tags: mysql, ado.net

I have a little problem with my MysqlConnection objets. I have those two connection strings in my app.config :

```
<connectionStrings>

    <add name="bdpvcLocalhost" connectionString="Persist Security Info=False;server=localhost;Uid=root;Password=***;database=bdpvc" providerName="Mysql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
    <add name="bdpvcProduction" connectionString="server=pvcserver.pvcservprod.local;user id=pvc_app;Pwd=***;database=bdpvc" providerName="Mysql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

The first connection is for a local test database, the second one is for the real production database. Since i am still early in the developpement, I use my local database. I then use the following code (I cut some of the Parameters definition cause there is really a lot)

```
using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(_connectionString))
{

   connection.Open();

   using (MySqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
   {
       const string sequenceQuery = "INSERT INTO sequence " +
                                    "(No_Sequence, No_Client, No_Produit, No_Version_Produit, " +
                                    " No_Soumission, No_Commande, No_Reference, Date_Livraison, " +
                                    "Date_Commande, Date_Soumission, Quantite, Status, Contact, " +
                                    "Notes, No_Production_Ancien, Erreur_Production, No_Fichier_Log, " +
                                    "No_Utilisateur, Date_Enregistrement, Extension_Fichier_Fax, Uuid) " +

                                    "VALUES(?No_Sequence, ?No_Client, ?No_Produit, ?No_Version_Produit, " +
                                    "?No_Soumission, ?No_Commande, ?No_Reference, ?Date_Livraison, ?Date_Commande, " +
                                    "?Date_Soumission, ?Quantite, ?Status, ?Contact, ?Notes, ?No_Production_Ancien, " +
                                    "?Erreur_Production, ?No_Fichier_Log, ?No_Utilisateur, ?Date_Enregistrement, " +
                                    "?Extension_Fichier_Fax, ?Uuid)";

       const string selectSequenceNoQuery =
           "SELECT MAX(No_Sequence) AS Valeur_No_Increment FROM sequence";

       const string updateSequenceNoQuery =
           "UPDATE tables SET Valeur_No_Increment = ?Valeur_No_Increment WHERE Nom_Tables = 'sequence'";

       int currentIncrement = 0;


       MySqlCommand selectNoSequenceCommand = new MySqlCommand(selectSequenceNoQuery, connection,
                                                               transaction);
       MySqlCommand updateNoSequenceCommand = new MySqlCommand(updateSequenceNoQuery, connection,
                                                               transaction);
       MySqlCommand insertSequenceCommand = new MySqlCommand(sequenceQuery, connection, transaction);

       //------------------------------
        //This query execute perfectly!
       currentIncrement = Int32.Parse(selectNoSequenceCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString());


       insertSequenceCommand.Parameters.Add("?No_Sequence", MySqlDbType.String);
       //Lots and lot of parameters definition

       foreach (Sequence sequence in _sequences)
       {
           currentIncrement++;

           sequence.No_Sequence = currentIncrement.ToString();


           insertSequenceCommand.Parameters["?No_Sequence"].Value = sequence.No_Sequence;
            //Lots and lots of value assignement

            //---------------------------------
            //But this one doesn't use the right user!
           insertSequenceCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

           Console.WriteLine("Inserted new sequence with Uuid " + sequence.Uuid + " and increment " +
                             sequence.No_Sequence);

       }

       updateNoSequenceCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Valeur_No_Increment", currentIncrement);
       updateNoSequenceCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

       transaction.Commit();
   }
}
```

The first query execute just fine. However, the second query isn't able to execute, because "the user `pvc_app` doesn't exists". *But I am connecting to my local database as root! And never in my code do I switch connection string!* I tried deleting the second connection string in app.config, but it kept trying to connect as `pvc_app`. I rebuild the application multiple time, rebooted my computer and even uninstalled/reinstalled the ADO.NET connector, but it kept trying to connect as pvc_app! Am I doing something wrong here?

Now, where is located this mysterious "connection string cache" so I can kill it with my bare hand? Cause it's really making my life a misery right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround of this problem was to create an another user with a default password. The connection was then working fine. It seem to be a bug with ADO.NET connector.